# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ConnectError' with Seperate Exceptions file

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am getting an error when I run my python code

This is my exceptions class (exceptions.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class ConnectError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        # Set some exception infomation
        self.msg = arg
```

Here is my connector class (connector.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import exceptions
class CardReader():
    def __init__(self):
        raise exceptions.ConnectError("ABC")
```

Here is my test file(test.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import connector

connect = connector()
```

This is what my code sorta looks like, I know that I should use a try and except in my test file, but before I get to that I get an error in the connector class (AttributeError). I have tried using

```
from exceptions import ConnectError
```

but that gives me an ImportError: cannot import name ConnectError, I have tried using this:

```
from exceptions import *
```

then I get NameError: name 'exceptions' is not defined, then I tried:

```
from exceptions import *
import exceptions
```

I still get AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ConnectError', I have flipped the import statements and I am stuck. I've been searching online, but I can't find anything that has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue, i renamed my exceptions.py to expection.py, i'm not sure why but i think the name was effecting something, i used the regular import exception. thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

While `ConnectError` is a subclass of `Exception`, it is not in the same module. So importing `exceptions` does not have the effect that you want. You need to import the file in which you declared `ConnectError`.

Don't `raise exceptions.ConnectError`. Just `raise ConnectError`.

Comment: sorry this might be a little stupid, but i thought i did import the file i declared ConnectError in, if you mean i need to import exceptions in my test.py, i have actually tried that

Comment: @user3810870 clarified

Comment: I did that and it gave me this NameError: name 'ConnectError' is not defined

I have this import statement: from exceptions import MSR605ConnectError
I have tried the regular import exceptions too